# Are all NextJS ServerActions exposed as public end points

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

Are all functions exported in a javascript file that is marked with "user server" publicly accessible or only those that are called from either Client or Server Components ?

I am using Auth.js to protect the server functions, but want to know if the code to check if a session is valid needs to be included in every exported function.

Example below:

actions.js

```
"use server"
import { dbCreateUser } from "./database";

export async function createUser(formData) {

    const email = formData.get('email');
    const password = formData.get('password');

    if (
        isInvalidText(email) ||
        isInvalidText(password) ||
        isInvalidText(name) 
    ) {
        throw new Error('Invalid form submission');
    }

    const user = {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        name: name
    }

    const result = await dbCreateUser(user);
}
```

database.js

```
export async function dbCreateUser(user) {
    const newUser = await prisma.users.create({
        data: {
            email: user.email,
            hashed_password: user.password,
            name: user.name,
        },
    })

    return newUser;
}
```

In the above two files, is it only `createUser` that is exposed as publicly callable endpoint even through `dbCreateUser` is used in that file but doesn't have "use server" >